# reset the value of a variable

Tags: graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

Folks, I have a problem in populating a matrix without overriding the values. After performing computations for various values for j, I want to store these values in following matrix. Here is the code:

```
For[i = 1, i <= 30, i++,
row1[i] = Sum[Score1[[i, j]], {j, 1, 30}]; 
row2[i] = Sum[Score2[[i, j]], {j, 1, 30}]; 
If[row1[i] > max1, max1 = row1[i]]; 
If[row2[i] > max2, max2 = row2[i]]; 
]

For[j = 1, j <= 10, j++,
 For[i = 1, i <= 30, i++,
  row1[i] = row1[i]/max1;
  row2[i] = row2[i]/max2;
  rankboard[[j, i]] = (j*10*row1[i]) + ((1 - j)*10*row2[i]); 
  ]
 ]
```

When I look up rankboard matrix, it shows up the following output:

[image]

It appears that on the next iteration of j, the values are being overridden.

I tried the following:

```
Clear[row1,row2]
```

I also tried this:

```
Block[row1,row2]
```

not sure if it made any difference.

The above command erases the values globally. What I want is to keep the values of row1 and row2 unchanged so I could produce output for different values of j.

Please can you help how to do that. Much appreciated.

Comment: Well, you are writing `row[i] = row[i]/max1`. How do you expect `row[i]` _not_ to change??

Comment: just do this: `rankboard[[j, i]] = (j*10*row1[i]/max1) + ((1 - j)*10*row2[i]/max2); ` without redefining `row1[i]`.

Comment: Thank you @george2079! so sorry, I was working on this for a long time didnt realize that it was trivial!